# pytest-django Use env vars in settings.py

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have an api in Django that uses quite a few environment variables. The idea is to add pytest-django to test all its functionalities (I know it would have been smarter to build the tests together with the project).

Currently it is in the manage.py file where I load the environment variables as follows:

```
def main():
    dotenv.read_dotenv()
```

And in my api settings.py file I use some of these environment variables as follows:

```
os.environ.get('one_key')
```

In my pytest.ini file I have correctly configured my settings.py as follows:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = api.settings
```

The problem is that when I run pytest I get the error that it does not find those environment variables, because the manage.py has not been executed and therefore these have not been loaded. Is there any way to make pytest load an .env before running the tests and the settings.py?

Comment: Run `dotenv.read_dotenv()` in `pytest_sessionstart` in your `conftest.py`

There is also 3rd party library, not sure if needed for such trivial task though: https://github.com/quiqua/pytest-dotenv

Comment: @Adam does `pytest_sessionstart` need to be decorated as a fixture or something? This isn't working for me. (Also just FYI, the pytest-dotenv library you linked to will break `dotenv.read_dotenv()` due to a namespace conflict between django-dotenv and python-dotenv (one of its dependencies)...at least that was my experience)

Comment: @GlenVaughan no need to decorate it. Just make sure that `conftest.py` is being read by pytest and declare `pytest_sessionstart` function in it.https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart

Comment: @GlenVaughan You might need to just pass path to `dotenv.read_dotenv`. Because by default it will look inside where `conftest.py` is located.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The suggestion of calling `dotenv.read_dotenv()` from `pytest_sessionstart()` in `conftest.py` did not work for me. I also tried the pytest-dotenv library that was linked. It made pytest work, but broke my manage.py module (due to a namespace conflict between django-dotenv [which my manage.py is using to read the .env file], and python-dotenv [which is a dependency of pytest-dotenv]).

Ultimately I ended up finding 
[pytest-django-dotenv](https://github.com/kaniak274/pytest-django-dotenv), which seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: `pytest-django-dotenv` is not working for me, returning this error: `AttributeError: module 'dotenv' has no attribute 'read_dotenv'. Did you mean: 'load_dotenv'?`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone passing by, `pytest-django-dotenv` is deprecated and is not actively maintained. A simple fix is simply to create a `conftest.py` in your **tests folder** and to add:

```
import dotenv

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    dotenv.load_dotenv("[TEST_ENV_FILE_PATH]")
```

Hope it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned solution with conftest.py to load the environment variables did not work for me if DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE was set in the pytest.ini. Somehow it would still try to load the settings before `pytest_sessionstart`.

So my solution was to define that variable in my `.env` file instead, which rendered my pytest.ini useless and i removed it.

With that, my conftest.py looks as follows:

```
import dotenv
import django

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    dotenv.load_dotenv()
    django.setup()
```

My `.env` file and my `conftest.py` reside in the root folder, my tests are placed like `app_name/tests/test_model.py`